# Entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, entitlements

I have been given a project which was released 2+ years ago, and had been developed by a third party who is no longer affiliated with us.
I am running it in xcode4.2 using iOS5.0 sdk, and have already built a few other apps using these without any problems. This project's deployment target is set to 3.2.1 as it is an older project and in theory should still work on older devices.

This project runs fine in the simulator, but not on a device. It starts up, loads the splash screen, and while loading other assets it crashes with no error dispayed in xcode. Using the device console in the organizer, I have noticed that it displays the error:

```
unknown install[20867] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

This error is displayed a few times at the beginning, and there is also a:

```
No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'appname:(null). Notifications will not be delivered.
```

I've created a new provisioning profile with push services enabled, and done all of the certificate stuff to go with it - I suspect this error is a follow on from the first error but I'm not sure. Previously when I had this problem it was because I was mistakingly building against a prov profile without push notifications configured - switching to the correct profile fixed this.

What's confusing is that I've tried removing the prov profile, restarting xcode, the mac and the device  - problem persists.
I've made sure that the bundle identifier in the plist matches the one used on the provisioning profile.
I'm unsure whether I need to change anything in the Entitlements.plist, previous applications I've made didn't have this file in it (I'm led to believe the requirement was removed in xcode 4?). At the moment the only line in that plist is "can be debugged", which I have tried as both true and false - neither have worked.

I've looked up previous questions on here, but have had no luck. If there was a problem with the provisioning profile I wouldn't even expect it to build, let alone display the splash screen.

Does anyone have any idea on what the problem could be?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: in case it's relevant the device I am using is a 3GS, on iOS 5.0. The crash happens regardless of whether I run directly from xcode, or archive the app is an ipa and copy it to the device.

Comment: If the app was originally published for Enterprise distribution, you need to make sure you are also doing the same thing.  If you're not checking the "Distribute for Enterprise" checkbox, this might happen.  For me, I tried this and my app installs using OTA installation from a website, but the app instantly disappears after the install completes.  The message in the console specifies that <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile.  Republishing as "Distribute for Enterprise" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the entitlements format changed, then it became auto generated when archiving an application.  Delete the entitlements file altogether and remove any references to it in the build settings.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't affected the errors at all, they are still there. I have removed the file itself and for both the project and target I have made sure that Build Settings->Code Signing -> Code Signing Entitlements is empty.

Comment: Check the bundle identifier in the summary pane.  Also, make sure you delete the application from your device before attempting to reinstall.  The old entitlements file could be hanging around.

Comment: Done both of those already. When I'm having problems with installs I ALWAYS delete the entire application from the device, and as I say the bundle identifier seems to be correct in every field that I can find it: summary, info and plist.

Comment: Does the project summary pane have entitlements enabled?  If so, disable it.  Was the provisioning profile generated recently?  If not, regenerate it.  Remember to remove old provisioning profiles from the device either through the Settings app or through Xcode's organiser window.

Comment: Entitlements are not enabled. A brand new provisioning profile was generated today, the original one I used was generated maybe a week ago. Profiles were wiped from device and then device restarted too. Never had this many complications with it, and it's a slightly convoluted process to begin with.

Comment: So in the end the problem just vanished. I opened up the pbxproj file to have a look for anything untoward - didn't make any changes to it - and when I tried again everything worked! I'll mark your answer as correct since they are the most likely causes of the problem ordinarily, just not on this occasion. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I face the same problem, and I found there are two kinds of profile:

- Ad hoc
- Distribution

I choose the wrong type so I can't install it. You can generate the profile and try again.

[image]